# Change paddings only on Blogger post pages

Tags: css, width, padding, blogger, posts

How can I change the paddings of the post body section in Blogger, but only on the post page, not on the home page of the blog.

This is the code where I am changing the paddings:

```
 .post-body {
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', 'helvetica', arial, sans-serif;
  color:#0e0e0f;
  font-size:18px;
  line-height:25px;
  font-weight:normal;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  text-transform:auto;
  word-wrap:break-word;

  text-align:justify;
}
```

I am changing `padding:0;` to `padding:0 40px 0 40px;`

The problem here is that I am using a grid/gallery style template on my blog, and when I change the padding using the above way, it changes the appearing of the posts on the home page, as well. Here is a screenshot:

[home page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0DEu.jpg)

What I want is to make my posts narrower, since currently they are too wide and may cause the reader to get tired of reading and leave my blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data:view.isSingleItem` to check if the current page is a single post or page.

Use the following code before `</head>`

```
<b:if cond="data:view.isSingleItem">
    <style>
        .post-body { padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px; }
    </style>
</b:if>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. It turned out that the 40pxs which I wanted were too much on a mobile device so I changed them to 5%. It has the same result as 40px on my desktop but on my phone is way better. BTW, thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear that.